# How to find parametric curve from differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, parametric, parametrization

How would you find the parametric curve for this set of parametric differential equations: $$x'=\frac{1}{y},y'=2xy$$
I tried dividing the second equation by the first and treating it as a normal differential equation. However, this results in a normal cartesian equation which can have multiple parametric representations, some of which don't satisfy the equations. How can I solve these equations while preserving their parametric nature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x''=-\dfrac {y'}{y^2}=-\dfrac {2x}y$$
$$x''=-2xx'$$
$$x''=-(x^2)'$$
Integrate.
$$x'=-x^2+C$$
This is separable.

Comment: After integrating I get $$ln|\frac{x+\sqrt{c_1}}{x-\sqrt{c_1}}|=2\sqrt{c_1}(t+c_2)$$ where $c_1$ is the first constant of integration that was created when integrating $x''$. I don't think it's possible to simplify this into $x(t)$, however.

Comment: You have to discuss the solution since it will depend on the value of the constant $C$ it can be zero or positive or negative. @Jacob And what you have is exactly $x(t)$ take the exponential on both sides and factorize $x(t)$

Comment: $$|\frac{x+\sqrt{c_1}}{x-\sqrt{c_1}}|=e^{2\sqrt{c_1}(t+c_2)}$$ Then factorize $x(t)$ ....

Comment: The initial conditions are $x(0)=0, y(0)=1$ which results in $c_2=0$ and simplifies the equation to $$|\frac{x+\sqrt{c_1}}{x-\sqrt{c_1}}|=e^{2\sqrt{c_1}t}$$

Comment: Then just factorize $x$ and you are done @Jacob

Comment: I don't understand how you would factorize x

Comment: $x+k=e^{2kt}(x-k)$ where $k=\sqrt {c_1}$ then $x(1-e^{2kt})=-ke^{2kt}-k$ is this more clear @Jacob ???

Comment: Ohh I got it thank you

Comment: Sorry it just clicked. Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: Then you can deduce $y$ easily since $y=1/x'$. You're welcome Jacob @Jacob